# PyCharm + AWS Toolkit Not Picking the correct Python Version for sam build from the IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, pycharm, aws-sam, aws-toolkit

I am following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-toolkits-for-pycharm-intellij-preview-and-visual-studio-code-preview/

I am getting an issue when I try to deploy the service from the PyCharm IDE. 
It's failing on sam build because it's picking the Python 2.7. But when I run sam build from the console with (penv) It's picking the correct python version.

You can see all on folloing screenshot
[image]

How can resolve this issue?